# Why is auto wired MockMvc null and controller not being instantiated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been following the spring boot 2.0.6 release documentation regarding testing a REST controller.  The documentation states that you simply annotate the test with @WebMvcTest(.class)

I have a test that is annotated as follows.

```
//@SpringBootTest(classes = FixingController.class)
//@TestPropertySource(properties = {
//    "security.basic.enabled=false",
//    "fixing.controller.enabled=true"
//})
//@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@WebMvcTest(FixingController.class)
public class FixingControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

But when I run the test, the mockMvc is null and my controller instance is not instantiated.  I have tried adding @MockBean references in the test as well and they are also not being created.

Given the documentation states that it is a simple case of using @WebMvcTest I am pulling my hair out as to why it is not working and how I go about understanding why not.  There are no errors in the console when I run the test.

**

- Solution

**

For anyone that is interested, I eventually got this working via the solution below. The @EnableWebMvc annotation is required as otherwise, the rest controller annotations are ignored and if you try and send content type = json in the POST request it returns a 415 status.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = FixingController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "fixing.controller.enabled=true" })
public class FixingControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;
```

Comment: Are you really following the Spring boot 2.0 documentation or are you following the current? As Spring Boot 2.0 still uses JUnit4 by default and not JUnit5 you need to include the proper dependencies and also make sure you are using the proper `@Test` annotation (the one from JUnit5 not from JUnit4).

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the JUnit4 dependency.  If I then switch `@Test` to JUnit4 instance and annotate the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` I then get the error below.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a `@SpringBootConfiguration`, you need to use `@ContextConfiguration` or `@SpringBootTest(classes=...)` with your test.

It still is not instantiating the associated controller class, but it has autowired the MockMvc instance and created the mock beans that the controller constructor requires.

Comment: Do you have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class

Comment: I do have a `@SpringBootApplication` class, but it basically auto configures so much extra stuff that I am not interested in.  I basically want to just test the class in isolation using MockMvc

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but the test needs to be able to detect that `@SpringBootApplication` class so it knows what parts of Spring MVC and optionally Spring Security it needs to cover. It is the starting point to detect what is needed.

Comment: So, I have managed to move slightly further forward with the annotations below.

`@SpringBootTest(classes = FixingController.class)`
`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`
`@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false, addFilters = false)`

But I am annoyingly getting the error `Content type 'application/json' not supported` but the REST controller clearly defines consume = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} and the test is clearly setting .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),

Comment: Please don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable. If this works the `@WebMvcTest` should also work. You apparently now also switched to JUnit5.